# É sempre possível que (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) possa ser avaliado como verdadeiro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

É possível que `(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)` possa ser avaliado como `true`?

Esta é uma pergunta de entrevista feita por uma grande empresa de tecnologia. Estou tentando encontrar a resposta. Eu sei que nunca escrevemos esse código no nosso dia-a-dia, mas tenho curiosidade.

Comment: O nome disso é [**INPUT**](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#INPUT).

Comment: Interessante, li a parte do **INPUT**, mais tarde vou ler o restante.

Comment: Na minha opinião isso é uma péssima pergunta de entrevista. Ninguém é obrigado a ficar pensando em casos mirabolantes como o da resposta que usa um objeto. Quando que isso vai ser útil na vida prática do funcionário?

Comment: Questões assim servem para medir velocidade e capacidade de raciocínio lógico e de propor soluções a problemas. Além de confrontar o condidato quanto a seu autocontrole, autodidatismo, determinação em resolver problemas, comunicação e expressão, pensamento crítico, síntético, objetivo. Não subestime uma questão boba de lógica de programação, pois ela diz muito de quem você realmente é.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/577181/112052

Answer (score 38, accepted):

É possível se `a` for um objeto constante que retorna valores que são incrementados cada vez que o objeto é invocado. No caso abaixo:

```
const a={
  valor: 1,
  valueOf: function(){
    return a.valor++;
  }
}
```

Na primeira invocação do `a` ele retornará `1`. Após isso, cada vez que `a` for chamado, irá retornar o último valor `+1` (1, 2 , 3...).

Logo, `(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)` será verdadeiro, porque `a` será igual a 1, 2 e 3 retornados da constante `a`.

Quando eu invoco `a == 1`, o valor de `a` é `1` (verdadeiro) e o `a` passa a ter valor `2`, logo `a == 2` também é verdadeiro, e assim por diante.

Para exemplificar, poderia fazer assim também que o resultado é o mesmo:

```js
const a={
   valor: 1,
   valueOf: function(){
      return a.valor++;
   }
}  

if(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3 && a == 4 && a == 5){
    // até esse "a" no console.log abaixo já incrementa o valor
    console.log("fim. O valor de a é "+a); 
}
```

Existe uma pergunta semelhante no **[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1377664)**.

Comment: Só não entendi a parte que diz que a resposta no SOen diz ser por causa de curto-circuito. Pelo o que li, ele afirma que isso funciona devido a comparação frouxa (*loose equality*) em que se compara apenas o valor de `a`, mas não não seu tipo que é onde daria problema ao comparar um objeto com um inteiro.

Comment: "Não tem nada a ver com short-circuit (curto-circuito) como propõe..." Não vejo nenhuma menção a short-circuit na resposta citada, nem tão pouco consigo perceber em que sentido diz estar errada/equivocada, uma vez que é igual á sua! (trocando o `toString` por `valueOf`)

Comment: @Isac É verdade, eu acabei me confundindo com outra resposta que vi em outro lugar rs. Acho que era o sono.

Comment: pergunta semelhante não, pergunta idêntica.

Answer (score 6):

Apenas para deixar registrado, seguem mais alguns casos em que isso é possível (todos retirados [desta pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127)).

Vale lembrar que estes métodos não são recomendados em sistemas sérios, pois tornam o código desnecessaramente confuso. Estão mais para curiosidades, mas acho que também serve para se aprofundar um pouco nos meandros da linguagem, e quem sabe evitar que se caia nessas situações sem querer.

Enfim, vamos às "bizarrices":

---

## Array

Ao comparar um array com um número usando o operador `==`, primeiro é feita a conversão do array para primitivo. E conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/577190/112052), para fazer esta conversão, ele procura pelos métodos `@@toPrimitive`, `valueOf` e `toString`, nesta ordem, e chama o primeiro que for encontrado. Depois, o retorno deste método é usado na comparação.

No caso específico de arrays, podemos nos valer do fato de que `toString()` chama internamente o método `join` (conforme [descrito na especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring)), então podemos alterá-lo assim:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.join = a.shift;
console.log(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3); // true
```

Ou seja, quando o array é comparado com um número, o método `toString()` chama o `join`, que por sua vez chamará `shift`, que é um método que remove o primeiro elemento do array e o retorna. Assim, cada vez que a comparação é feita, ele retorna o próximo elemento do array.

---

## Objetos

Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/577190/112052) (e pelo exemplo dado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271452/112052)), um objeto pode ter um método `valueOf` que incrementa seu valor, ou seja, a cada invocação ele retorna um valor diferente.

Mas só para detalhar mais, o operador `==` primeiro converte o objeto para primitivo, e para isso ele procura pelos métodos `@@toPrimitive`, `valueOf` e `toString`, e chama o primeiro que encontrar. Então o método descrito na outra resposta funciona também se o objeto tiver quaisquer um destes métodos, desde que façam a mesma coisa (retornem um valor diferente a cada invocação). Veja o [link já indicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/577190/112052) para uma explicação mais detalhada.

Sabendo disso, podemos usar qualquer método que retorne um valor diferente a cada invocação, como por exemplo, usando uma regex que retorne o próximo *match* de uma string contendo dígitos:

```js
var a = {
  r: /\d/g, 
  valueOf: function() {
    // cada vez que exec é chamado, retorna o próximo dígito
    return this.r.exec('123')[0];
  }
};

if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
    console.log("todos iguais");
}
```

Ou retornar números aleatórios (não vai dar certo sempre, claro, mas alguma hora acontecerá):

```js
var a = {
    valueOf: function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    }
};
// tenta mil vezes (se não der certo nenhuma, é muito azar)
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
        console.log(`Todos iguais, depois de ${i} tentativas`);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

## Unicode (sempre ele)

Isso é meio que "trapaça", já que o nome de duas variáveis não é exatamente `a`:

```js
var aﾠ = 1;
var a = 2;
var ﾠa = 3;
if (aﾠ==1 && a== 2 &&ﾠa==3) {
    console.log("todos iguais");
}
```

Note que a primeira e terceira variáveis possuem um espaçamento diferente (a primeira tem um espaço a mais depois do `a`, a terceira tem antes). Este "espaço" na verdade é o caractere [HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffa0/index.htm) (um caractere coreano). Apesar de ser renderizado como um espaço, ele não é reconhecido como um *whitespace*, pois pertence à [categoria "Letter, Other"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm).

Além disso, segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#sec-names-and-keywords), identificadores podem começar com qualquer caractere Unicode que tenha a propriedade `ID_Start`, e depois podem ter quaisquer caracteres que tenham a propriedade `ID_Continue`, e o HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER se encaixa nesses critérios. Portanto, "a" seguido do HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER é um nome válido, e HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER seguido de "a" também.

Ou seja, neste caso estamos na verdade com três variáveis diferentes. Mas como o nome de duas delas possuem um caractere que é renderizado como espaço, fica parecendo que estamos comparando a mesma variável.

Além disso, também é possível (embora nada recomendável) usar os caracteres [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) e [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200C/index.htm) nos nomes de variáveis. Isso deixa mais obscuro ainda, já que eles não são renderizados (afinal, "zero width" indica que eles não têm largura):

```js
var a= 1;
var a‍= 2; // depois do "a" tem um zero width joiner
var a‌= 3; // depois do "a" tem um zero width non-joiner
if (a==1 && a‍==2 && a‌==3) {
    console.log("todos iguais");
}
```

---

Enfim, há muitos outros truques similares na [pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127). E mais uma vez, nenhum deles é recomendado em aplicações sérias. Estão mais para curiosidades, que servem para mostrar os limites da linguagem.