# Por que um objeto comparado com vários números diferentes é verdadeiro?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, tipagem, comparação

Pegando o seguinte código:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    toString: function() { return this.i++; }
}
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3); // true
```

É um truque engenhoso (de utilidade duvidosa) usado em algumas entrevistas para a pessoa mostrar que conhece a linguagem. Mas por que ele funciona?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271444/%c3%89-sempre-poss%c3%advel-que-a-1-a-2-a-3-possa-ser-avaliado-como-verda/271452#271452

Comment: Não vi que tinha essa. De qualquer forma dei outra abordagem, coloquei algo novo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), o operador `==` usa o algoritmo descrito na [operação `IsLooselyEqual`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islooselyequal). O caso da pergunta cai no passo 12:

> *IsLooselyEqual ( x, y )*
> *...*
> *12. If x is an Object and y is either a String, a Number, a BigInt, or a Symbol, return ! IsLooselyEqual(? ToPrimitive(x), y).*

Ou seja, o objeto `x` é passado para a [operação `ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toprimitive). O algorimo primeiro procura pelo [método `toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive), mas no código da pergunta este método não existe, então ele cai no último passo:

> *ToPrimitive ( input [ , preferredType ] )*
> *...*
> *c. If preferredType is not present, let preferredType be number.*
> *d. Return ? OrdinaryToPrimitive(input, preferredType).*

Como o passo 12 de `IsLooselyEqual` não informou o `preferredType`, então ele foi setado para `number`, e em seguida foi chamada a [operação `OrdinaryToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-ordinarytoprimitive), que é descrita como:

> *OrdinaryToPrimitive ( O, hint )*
> *The abstract operation OrdinaryToPrimitive takes arguments O (an Object) and hint (string or number) and returns either a normal completion containing an ECMAScript language value or a throw completion. It performs the following steps when called:*
>
> 1. *If hint is string, then*
>
>    - *Let methodNames be « "toString", "valueOf" ».*
> 2. *Else,*
>
>    - *Let methodNames be « "valueOf", "toString" ».*
> 3. *For each element name of methodNames, do*
>
>    - *Let method be ? Get(O, name).*
>    - *If IsCallable(method) is true, then*
>
>      - *Let result be ? Call(method, O).*
>      - *If result is not an Object, return result.*
> 4. *Throw a TypeError exception.*

No caso, o `hint` é `number`, então primeiro ele verifica se o objeto possui o método `valueOf`: se possuir, chama-o e o retorna o resultado, caso contrário, procura pelo método `toString`.

---

Ou seja, no caso do objeto criado na pergunta, ao fazer `x == 1`, primeiro ele chama a operação `ToPrimitive(x)`, cujo resultado é o retorno de `toString()`.

Depois é feita a comparação `IsLooselyEqual(? ToPrimitive(x), y)`, que vai comparar uma string (retorno de `toString()`) com um número. E aí caímos neste passo da operação:

> *6. If x is a String and y is a Number, return ! IsLooselyEqual(! ToNumber(x), y).*

Ou seja, o retorno de `toString` será convertido para número e comparado com `y`.

---

O que acontece é que cada vez que `toString` é chamado, ele incrementa o valor de `i`. Por isso que a cada vez que a comparação é feita, o resultado é um número diferente.

E de acordo com o já descrito acima, o mesmo funcionaria se o objeto tivesse somente o método `valueOf` ou `toPrimitive`. Ou, mesmo que tivesse mais de um desses métodos, a prioridade é primeiro procurar por `toPrimitive`, depois `valueOf` e por último `toString`.

Por exemplo, neste caso o método `valueOf` está definido, então é ele que será usado:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    valueOf: function () {
        console.log('chamando valueOf');
        return this.i++;
    },
    toString: function () {
        console.log('chamando toString');
        return 'abc';
    }
};

console.log('teste 1');
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3); // true
console.log('teste 2');
console.log(x == 'abc'); // false
```

A saída deste código é:

```
teste 1
chamando valueOf
chamando valueOf
chamando valueOf
true
teste 2
chamando valueOf
false
```

Ou seja, `toString` nunca é chamado, porque a especificação da linguagem define que `valueOf` é verificado primeiro (se existir, chama e nem olha para `toString`).

---

Da mesma forma, o método `toPrimitive` tem prioridade sobre `valueOf` (ele só é um pouco mais chato de definir porque temos que usar o [respectivo `Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive)):

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]: function() {
        console.log('chamando toPrimitive');
        return this.i++;
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        console.log('chamando valueOf');
        return 42;
    },
    toString: function () {
        console.log('chamando toString');
        return 'abc';
    }
};

console.log('teste 1');
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3); // true
console.log('teste 2');
console.log(x == 'abc'); // false
console.log(x == 42); // false
```

Agora podemos ver que somente o método `toPrimitive` é chamado:

```
teste 1
chamando toPrimitive
chamando toPrimitive
chamando toPrimitive
true
teste 2
chamando toPrimitive
false
chamando toPrimitive
false
```

---

## Resumindo

Ao comparar um objeto com um número, primeiro o objeto é convertido para número:

- se o objeto possui o método `toPrimitive`, este é chamado e o seu retorno é usado na comparação
- caso `toPrimitive` não exista, verifica se o objeto possui o método `valueOf`, e este é chamado e o seu retorno é usado na comparação
- caso `valueOf` não exista, verifica se o objeto possui o método `toString`, e este é chamado e o seu retorno é usado na comparação
- se nenhum dos métodos existir, o resultado da comparação será `false`

Answer (score 5):

Sabe quando as pessoas falam que JavaScript é uma linguagem ruim?

Bem, muitas vezes a pessoa não entende bem do que está falando e repete algo que ouviu.

JavaScript tem defeitos como todas as linguagens, mas um defeito poucas linguagens possuem e dão essa fama para JS. É a tipagem fraca. Não a tipagem dinâmica ([veja as diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101)).

Pegamos algo mais completo:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    toString: function() { return this.i++; }
}
console.log(typeof(x));
console.log(typeof(1));
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3);
```

Em tipagem forte não é possível comparar um `object` com um `number`, os tipos não batem e é uma operação inválida. Na tipagem fraca a linguagem deve fazer o melhor esforço para resolver isso.

E não tem nada, neste código, que permite um objeto genérico ser transformado para um número e fazer a comparação funcionar. O oposto também é verdadeiro já que um número não pode ter a forma de um objeto específico. Isso é possível se a linguagem tiver uma maneira de criar um operador implícito de *cast* que faça a conversão para tornar o processo compatível. Bem, vamos deixar essa parte para depois.

De acordo com a tipagem dinâmica ele vai aonde dá, então transforma não só o objeto em uma `string`, que é uma forma universal, mas também faz o mesmo com o outro objeto que é do tipo número. Na verdade, ele faz isto:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    toString: function() { return this.i++; }
}
console.log(x.toString() == "1");
```

Obviamente deve saber que a linguagem tem a forma que não permite isto:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    toString: function() { return this.i++; }
}
console.log(x === 1 && x === 2 && x === 3);
```

O uso de `==` deveria ser quase proibido.

Mas o problema ainda não é bem esse.

O truque é um abuso do `toString()` que cria [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101) em algo que deveria ser [puro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/101). Nenhum problema fazer isso em outro método, mas nesse.

Também funciona:

```js
var x = {
    i: 1,
    valueOf: function() { return this.i++; },
    toString: function() { return this.i++; }
}
console.log(x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3);
console.log(typeof(x.valueOf()));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Equality.js).

Note que tendo uma maneira de pegar um valor ele prefere. Lembrando que se escrito corretamente ele deve retornar um primitivo, e só faz sentido um valor que se espera, como o dado numérico que ele guarda.

Este método é uma forma limitada de *cast* implícito que o JS permite. O `toString()` não deixa de ser também, mas este dá algo mais próximo do desejado.

Fazendo assim ainda é um truque abusivo, mas não tem o problema da tipagem dinâmica, portando o foco do problema é o efeito colateral inadequado.

Por isso que eu sempre falo que é uma bobagem uma linguagem não colocar algo porque poderá ser abusado. è possível abusar virtualmente com tudo. Por exemplo Java não quer ter sobrecarga de operadores, mas um simples `toString()` já pode causar o mesmo problema. C# tem essa sobrecarga e ninguém faz a multiplicação executar uma divisão, e se fizer tá errado, como no exemplo aqui. Eu já te disse alguma vez que funcionar é diferente de estar certo?

Eu não sou contra este tipo de teste em entrevistas, mas ele precisa ser olhado com cuidado. Obviamente que ele não serve para contratar Júnior.

Mas se mandarem você justificar isto: `aﾠ==1 && a== 2 &&ﾠa==3` dá verdadeiro também, sem nada de criar um objeto próprio, as variáveis são numéricas do jeito padrão da linguagem. Tem certo contexto, claro. Aí o truque é outro, os mais atentos ou que entendem de *lexing* vão matar fácil, outros precisarão de ferramenta auxiliar (já dei muita dica).

Se vai comentar dizendo o que acontece, tenta esconder a apresentação direta para não dar *spoiler* para quem lê de forma desavisada.

Tem mais truque parecido que dá para fazer, e ficar menos óbvio ainda, a olho nu ou usando outros *corner cases* da linguagem para gerar esse resultado.

Comment: Sobre o `aﾠ==1 && a== 2 &&ﾠa==3`, desculpe estragar a surpresa, mas deixei [uma resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/577805/112052) explicando esse e outros casos

Comment: Aqui não estraga, a pessoa tem que ir lá ver :)